# Flex: flexlib Base64Image not working locally?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, base64

I recreated this [example of using Base64Image](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib/blob/master/examples/Base64IMage/src/Base64Image_Sample.mxml) but it does not work when ran locally, only when I load it from a web server. Is this expected and can it be done so that it works locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected

Yes, it's because of security issues.

> can it be done so that it works locally?

Not in a web browser that is opening the file directly. To get it to work 'locally' you could host the file in a local web server, or turn your flex app into an AIR app.